# Gmail confirm action in inbox not showing up after months being approved by the markup team

Tags: google-schemas

In the company, we have diligently pursued the activation of the feature over the past several months with the Email Markup Reviews Team. Our requests were meticulously submitted, subsequently validated, and duly approved. Despite the approvals, there has been an unexpected delay in the functionality of the feature after waiting for an extended period.

After some back and forth with the validation team, we have been told "Our team is related to the functional review process and we do not have visibility nor provide guidance or assistance on the code or technical implementation directly".

Everything looks correct from, sending out emails, we can see the script chunk but no button is showing up

```js
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "EmailMessage",
        "potentialAction": {
            "@type": "ConfirmAction",
            "name": "Confirm email",
            "handler": {
                "@type": "HttpActionHandler",
                "url": "https://example.com/confirm_url_blah_blah_blah"
            }
        },
        "description": "To confirm your email address please tap this button"
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It could be a permission issue